# Manhua(?) where both the male and female lead get reincarnated

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

Here's a few things I remember:

- The male and female lead were a couple in a neglectful, unhappy marriage.
- The female lead dies while spitting blood after getting poisoned by her husband's mistress.
- As she lay in a pool of her blood, her husband walks in stunned and upset that she's passed away.
- The husband becomes obsessed with his wife, beside himself with grief that she is actually gone.
- He kept her dead body preserved and unburied until he was old and gray and would even dance with her deceased body, alarming the servants.
- Both were reincarnated with full memories of their past.

I don't remember what either of them look like.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did the story take place in the distant past or in a modern/future setting?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: It was a historical setting

Comment: Do they reincarnate in the past or in the present/future? Or into another world/a story? What happens after they reincarnate?

Comment: They reincarnate to a few years before her death, same people and life, she has full knowledge of what's going to happen and her husband does too. He tries to make it right but she's wanting a divorce.